# '-LOCAL' solution deployment across multi server farm

Tags: solution-deployment, load-balancing

I've deployed numerous solutions before but I'm trying to do a 'zero downtime' deployment on a 4 server farm.
My question is about what happens in the background when deploying with the -local parameter.
I'm using our DNS load balancer to get unrestricted access to each WFE but the App servers don't serve pages to users, just search and indexing and other service apps.
When I use the -local parameter in my deployment script, when does the app pool get recycled and how does the status of all 4 servers get sync'd in the config database?

As you can tell I'm still a bit uncertain about this process and would much rather get the downtime approved than 'faff' about.

Thanks in advance.

N03L.